# How can I set rules in MS Exchange Server 2000

Tags: exchange

My Outlook is already full of rules and I want my exchange server to do some rules for me. I don't know where to start inside the MS Exchange. Any ideas?

-Thank you for that. Scenario here is that I need to receive all the emails from outside and I auto-forward it to my agents. every agents have 1 rule and we are expanding so my capacity, w/c is 32kb is not enough. What do you think is the best way I can do?

Comment: What types of rules? And, any reason to be using something 3 versions behind on a product like Exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook rules are created strictly in the outlook client. Rules may be stored on the client (client side rules) or on the server (server side rules) depending on what they do. Also, there's a 32KB limit to the rules on anything prior to Exchange 2007, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for that. Scenario here is that I need to receive all the emails from outside and I auto-forward it to my agents. every agents have 1 rule and we are expanding so my capacity, w/c is 32kb is not enough. What do you think is the best way I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what type of rules you are creating, but by default Outlook **will** store and process some of its rules on the exchange server depending on what types of rules you create.

Ref: http://www.slipstick.com/rules/serverbased.htm and http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/12/10/447717.aspx